# Using Media Queries with Class Names to Change Website Width

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a mobile application that I want to blow up full-screen. Twitter Bootstrap gives me the size for phones, tablets, and all that information. I would like a CSS class to handle all of the different types of sizes. I'm looking for something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) classname

@media (max-width: 767px) classname
```

etc

Comment: I'm not sure of what you really want, but these links should help you a bit: ["Mobifying" your HTML5 site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/) , [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this?

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .classname {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .classname {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Note that the media query with the smaller `max-width` is set last to allow it to override the media query with the larger `max-width`.

See [this article](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) for more on using media queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can also change css according to the html element and id.
The `max-width` works from 0 to max **given** width or if `min-width` is given then from given `min-width` with to `max-width`.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #YourElementId{
        width:100%;
    }
    YourElementName {
        width:80%;
    }
}
```

Above css will work from 0 to **max** given **width** of the media screen.

On the other hand, `min-width` works for more than given width for example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #YourElementID {
        width:80%; 
    }
    body {
        width:75%; 
    }
}
```

This will work only if the width of media screen's **width** is **more than 768px**.